# Write a hasNoneLetters function

Tags: javascript

Write a hasNoneLetters function that takes 2 strings phrase and blacklist and returns true, if phrase does not contain any letters from blacklist, otherwise returns false.

Comparison should be case-insensitive, it means x inside blacklist does not allow using X.

Examples:

```
hasNoneLetters('Mate Academy', 'pqrs') === true;
hasNoneLetters('ABC', 'a') === false;
```

my answer was:

```
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  if(phrase.includes(blacklist)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

but one test didn't passed saying 'It should return true if no matching letters' mine returned false;

Comment: The question asks you to write a **case-insensitive** match. Also, using `includes` looks for the whole substring in the initial string, while you want to iterate through all the letters.

Comment: Can you write it for me ?

Comment: `.., it means x inside blacklist does not allow using X.`  Is it me, or does that not make any sense?.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  const r = new RegExp(`[${blacklist}]`, 'i')
  return Boolean(phrase.match(r))
}

console.log(hasNoneLetters('Mate Academy', 'pqrs'))
console.log(hasNoneLetters('ABC', 'a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking with the `includes` method, you're only looking if the string passed in arguments is contains inside the other string.

For example :

| Phrase | blacklist | expected return | return value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | hl | false | true |

while your code was working for substrings like this

| Phrase | blacklist | expected return | return value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | hel | true | true |
| World | ld | true | true |

To make the program work, you need to *loop* through all the characters and check if those are included in the string !

Example

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  const letters = blacklist.split('')
  
  for (const letter of letters){
    if (phrase.includes(letter)) return false
  }
  
  return true
} 

console.log(hasNoneLetters("Hello world", "ab")) // true
console.log(hasNoneLetters("Hello world", "abcd")) // false
```

---

Note : as @albjerto mentionned, you should also check with case sensitivity.

This can be done using the `toLowerCase` method on the phrase and the blacklist.

Example :

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {

  const lowerPhrase = phrase.toLowerCase()
  const lowerBlacklist = blacklist.toLowerCase()
  const letters = lowerBlacklist.split('')
  
  for (const letter of letters){
    if (lowerPhrase.includes(letter)) return false
  }
  
  return true
} 

console.log(hasNoneLetters("Hello world", "ab")) // true
console.log(hasNoneLetters("Hello world", "abcD")) // false
console.log(hasNoneLetters("HeLlO world", "O")) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the blacklist string into individual characters and compare every character in `phrase` with each upper- & lower-case character from `blacklist`. Something like this:

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  let forbidden = blacklist.split('');
  return forbidden.every(char => {
    return !phrase.includes(char.toLowerCase()) && !phrase.includes(char.toUpperCase());
  });
}



console.log('should be true', hasNoneLetters('Abracadabra', 'mstvz'));
console.log('should be false', hasNoneLetters('Abracadabra', 'c'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert two strings params to either lowercase or uppercase and then loop over every character in  the blacklist string

```js
function hasNoneLetters(phrase, blacklist) {
  blacklist.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(function(c) {
    if(phrase.toLowerCase().includes(c) {
       return true;
    } 
  });
  return false
}
```